# SDL2 Toggle fullscreen: Window position gets reset

Tags: c++, windows, sdl-2

I'm attempting to toggle fullscreen in SDL2 and so far it works. However when the mode returns to windowed mode, the position gets reset to 0, 0. I tried storing the last position of the window before the window goes fullscreen but after it returns to windowed, the positon gets reset to 0,0 still.

I'm outputting the last position and it seems correct, yet it still gets reset to 0,0 when returning to windowed. Do I need to listen for an event or something?

```
void ToggleFullscreen(SDL_Window* window) {
    Uint32 flag = SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN;
    bool isFullscreen = SDL_GetWindowFlags(window) & flag;
    if(!isFullscreen){
        SDL_GetWindowPosition(window, &lastWindowX, &lastWindowY);
    }

    SDL_SetWindowFullscreen(window, isFullscreen ? 0 : flag);

    if(isFullscreen){
        cout << "set window to: " << lastWindowX << " " << lastWindowY << endl;
        SDL_SetWindowPosition(window, lastWindowX, lastWindowY);
    }

}
```

Comment: I tested your code and it should work. Are you sure you're not setting `lastWindowX` and `lastWindowY` to 0 somewhere else?

Comment: It works on some machines but not others. I'm not sure why. I've tried doing an asynchronous timer after setting it from fullscreen to window and after 2 seconds I set the position then. It seems to work sometimes but also sometimes the border changes to borderless.

There must be some kind of fullscreen toggle code somewhere online but I seriously cannot find one at all. SDL2 seems so unsupported these days.

Comment: Have you tried using `SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP` instead of `SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN`?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at one of my projects that has a function to set either windowed, fullscreen or fullscreen desktop I found these two lines:

```
// Fixes problem when Game::changeResolution is called in fullscreen or fullscreen desktop and then return to windowed.
SDL_SetWindowSize(m_pWindow, m_width, m_height);
SDL_SetWindowPosition(m_pWindow, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 
SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED);
```

With the `SDL_SetWindowSize` done first, everything works fine. Then I commented out the `SDL_SetWindowSize` line and ran again. When returning from `SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP`, it reset it's position to `(0,0)`.

Although when returning to windowed from `SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN`, it was placed okay. Try adding that line and see if it fixes the problem for you. Also try adding in `SDL_Delay(2000);` between calls.